# How to only ensure authenticated on some functions in elixir module

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to implement [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) jwt in an phoenixframework project.

I have a user_controller.ex module with the following functions: index, create, show, update, and delete

I only want to make sure users are authenticated on update and delete

If I put `plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, handler: SessionController` at the top of the module *all* function require authentication.

I tried to do this:

`plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, %{ on_failure: { SessionController, :unauthenticated } } when not action in [:index, :create, :show]`, which *does* work as desired but I get the following error in the console: `[warn] :on_failure is deprecated. Use the :handler option instead`

So the question is: How to only require authentication on update and delete using the handler argument?

Comment: Does `plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, [handler: SessionController] when not action in [:index, :create, :show]` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, [handler: SessionController] when action in [:update, :delete]`